# Get week date that starts on monday in standard sql

Tags: google-bigquery

In legacy_sql, `UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK` has `day_of_week` argument to specify what day of week the week is counted from. But in standard SQL, `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp>, WEEK)` don't have this argument and it defaults to Sunday.

Is there any clean workaround except: `TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp>, WEEK), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`?

Comment: issues has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now available and is documented in the release notes:

`INTERSECT DISTINCT` and `EXCEPT DISTINCT` are now supported set operators in standard SQL.

`FARM_FINGERPRINT` is now a supported function in legacy SQL.

`WEEK(<WEEKDAY>)` is now a valid date part for the `EXRACT` function.

There is now a quota of 300 concurrent API requests per user.

Cloud IAM `custom roles` are now available for BigQuery.

The `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column is now supported when querying data using a wildcard table over partitioned tables.

More info at [Google Cloud Platform release document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#november_30_2017)

Answer (score 6):

I [filed a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64689667) to support specifying the start day of WEEK boundaries for `DATE_TRUNC`/`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC` and other date/timestamp functions, so please star the issue to express interest and receive updates. In the meantime, you can express this logic as a temporary function:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TimestampTruncToMonday(t TIMESTAMP) AS (
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(t, INTERVAL 1 DAY), WEEK),
    INTERVAL 1 DAY
  )
);

SELECT
  t,
  TimestampTruncToMonday(t) AS monday
FROM UNNEST([
  TIMESTAMP '2017-08-17',
  TIMESTAMP '2017-06-25',
  TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01'
]) AS t;
```

Edit: now that BigQuery supports `WEEK(<WEEKDAY>)`, this is much simpler:

```
SELECT
  t,
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t, WEEK(MONDAY)) AS monday
FROM UNNEST([
  TIMESTAMP '2017-08-17',
  TIMESTAMP '2017-06-25',
  TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01'
]) AS t;
```